# /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not found in amazon linux ami

Tags: centos, rhel, amazon-linux

I am trying to run one of my `node.j`s project in amazone linux ami (AWS cloud) but i got the following error to while running the project.

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not found
```

I got this https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error thread its similar to my issue.

But my OS is not ubuntu its amazone linux ami so how can i fix it??

**UPDATE**

I found some similar packages with this command
`yum search libstdc++`

But don't know which is proper version here is the search result

```
compat-libstdc++-33.i686 : Compatibility standard C++ libraries
compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64 : Compatibility standard C++ libraries
libstdc++-devel.noarch : Header files and libraries for C++ development
libstdc++-docs.x86_64 : Documentation for the GNU standard C++ library
libstdc++-static.noarch : Static libraries for the GNU standard C++ library
libstdc++44.i686 : GNU Standard C++ Library
libstdc++44.x86_64 : GNU Standard C++ Library
libstdc++44-devel.x86_64 : Header files and libraries for C++ development
libstdc++44-static.x86_64 : Static libraries for the GNU standard C++ library
libstdc++48.i686 : GNU Standard C++ Library
libstdc++48.x86_64 : GNU Standard C++ Library
libstdc++48-devel.x86_64 : Header files and libraries for C++ development
libstdc++48-static.x86_64 : Static libraries for the GNU standard C++ library
```